# How to change a certain value of an array of POSIXct values to another one in R?

Tags: r

For an array of POSIXct values:

```
2015-01-01 10:04
2015-01-01 10:05
2015-01-01 10:10
2015-01-01 10:20
2015-01-01 10:30
2015-01-02 11:04
2015-01-02 11:30
..
```

I'd like to change the date `2015-01-02` to `2015-02-03`. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change only the date portion of a given entry, e.g. `2015-01-02 11:04` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for reply. No, I want to change all the date portion with a certain date. So both `2015-01-01 10:04` and `2015-01-02 11:30` should be changed in this case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oh I thought I had misunderstood what you meant. If you are talking about change `2015-01-02 11:30` to `2015-02-03 11:30`, then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first attempt was to somehow separately extract the date and timestamp portions of the `POSIXct` vector, replace the date as you wanted, and then roll it back up to a new `POSIXct` vector.  However, this seemed to lead nowhere fast, so then I tried just converting the `POSIXct` vector to character, and then using `gsub()` to make the date replacement.  After this, the character vector can easily be converted back to a `POSIXct` vector.

```
y <- as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01 10:30", "2015-01-02 11:04", "2015-01-02 11:30"),
                format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
y.replace <- gsub("2015-01-02", "2015-02-03", as.character(y))
result <- as.POSIXct(y.replace, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

> result
[1] "2015-01-01 10:30:00 MYT" "2015-02-03 11:04:00 MYT"
[3] "2015-02-03 11:30:00 MYT"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can this way handle the case that there are several dates to be changed? Sorry it is not clear enough in my question.

Comment: @ZICHAOLI I believe my solution _does_ handle multiple replacements.  Just look closely at the output: all instances of `2015-01-02` have been changed to `2015-02-03`.